# Parse a changing table

Tags: java, jsoup, html-table

I would like to parse a table with Jsoup for android/java, but the problem is I'm getting the table online from a site, the table is a school schedule.
The table online is always changing because of the schedules are always different than the week before.

The table exists of 10 rows (days and 9 hours), and 6 columns (which hour and 5 Days), each filled with, if there is a lesson, 3 or 4 `<td>` But if there isn't a lesson on that hour, one hour cell is just filled with one `<td>` tag.

My question is how do I parse a table which is always changing.
It can also be possible to parse only the first row and making a String of it, and after that parse the first cell in that row and making a String of it. And than check whether that cell has 1, 3 or 4 `<td>` tags in it.

Comment: Could you provide an exemple of the table ? How many times does it changes a week ? Can't you retreive the table each time you start your application ?

Comment: show us the html of the table and your attempt to access it via JSoup. The url would help too. It is not really clear what your problem is to me. Of course you can parse a table with Jsoup. That is the purpose of such a parser.

Comment: There is no difference in how you parse an "changes once a week" table and how you parse a "never changes" table; in the one that updates frequently, you should parse it frequently to get the latest values, but the parsing itself is identical.

Comment: No, the problem is that by example in week 1 on tuesday first hour a lesson is(so there will be 4 td tags), and in week 2 not(only 2 td tags), so if i say take the 31th <td> in the first week is it another td tag than when I say it in the second week